# Increasing sequence of reduced closed subschemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

[image: Morel's An introduction to A1-homotopy theory lemma 3.3.7]

Let $k$ be a perfect field, $V$ be an irreducible smooth $k$-scheme and $W$ is an open dense subset of $V$. Let $F$ be the complement of $W$.

In this lemma, Morel states that there is an increasing sequence of reduced closed subschemes:

$$\emptyset= F_{-1}\subset F_0\subset\dots\subset F_d=F$$
such that each $k$-scheme $F_s-F_{s-1}$ is smooth and $\dim F_i=i$.

I have no ideal about this decomposition. How is this sequence deduced?

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Hint: since $k$ is perfect, the singular locus has a nice description + property that will be useful here. What do you know that detects smoothness?

Comment: As I know, in this case, regular implies smooth.

Comment: Okay, but suppose someone gives you a scheme and says "where is this smooth?" How do you answer them? Can you compute the singular/nonsingular locus? If you can answer this question, you should have a major piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Local at a point is a regular local ring. But I don't know how tu compute singular locus.

Comment: Surely you have heard of the Jacobian criteria?

Comment: Yes, I heard that.